# node.js pdf2json how to parse PDF from array?

Tags: node.js

I am using node version 7.10.0 with:

pdf2json    version 1.1.7
mail parser version 2.0.5
smtp-server version 3.0.1

I have received an email with a PDF attachment and I want to parse the PDF using pdf2json without saving the PDF to disk, I have the byte array from the email attachment.  How can I parse this directly to the module?

I thought I could do this:

```
    const pdfParser     = require("pdf2json");

    let objPDF = new pdfParser();
    objPDF.parseBuffer(arybytContent);
```

Where 'arybytContent' is the content from the mail attachment:

```
    arybytContent = objAttachment["content"]["data"];
```

Looking at objPDF using Chrome, it doesn't look like the content has been parsed correctly, have a used the class incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that assigning the data in the way I was results in the "data" being returned as an array of bytes and this is completely different to what the parseBuffer method expects, so the solution is to convert the array to a buffer:

```
    new Buffer(objAttachement["content"]["data"]);
```

This can then be passed to the "parseBuffer" method.